# nvapi set active eye return error

Tags: c++, directx, stereo-3d, directx-10, nvapi

I am using nvapi with c++;

```
NvAPI_Initialize();

NvAPI_Stereo_Enable();

NvAPI_Stereo_IsEnabled(ref IsStereoEnabled);

NvAPI_Stereo_SetDriverMode(NVAPI_STEREO_DRIVER_MODE_DIRECT);

NvAPI_Stereo_CreateHandleFromIUnknown(device, &stere_handle);
```

I implemented this part of nvapi without problem. They all return NvAPI_OK. But After this calls, when I try to set active eye it returns NVAPI_SET_NOT_ALLOWED.

```
//Left and right eye rendering:
NvAPI_Stereo_SetActiveEye(right); then render scene
NvAPI_Stereo_SetActiveEye(left); then render scene
```

Anyone knows why it is not returning NvAPI_OK ?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem. I am writing to solution in case anyone faces same problem.

you have to call NvAPI_Stereo_SetDriverMode(NVAPI_STEREO_DRIVER_MODE_DIRECT);

function before directx device creation. If you call this after device creation it returns ok but it does not apply direct mode to device.